# Unable to import pango in python2

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pango

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.dullroar.com/training-tesseract.html) to set up and train the Tesseract 3 OCR tool.  Some of the scripts use Pango.  When I run the scripts, Python fails to import Pango.

```
ImportError: No module named pango
```

I have tried to install the following packages, along with attempting to build Pango and Cairo from scratch as detailed [here](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/11481/how-to-install-pango-and-cairo-pangocairo-for-python)

```
libpango1.0-0
libpango1.0-dev
libpangox1.0-0
```

What am I missing?  Is there a library I haven't installed/built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the Python bindings. The packages listed only contain the native libraries and development files. Try completing the instructions in the linked article by installing PyGTK.